# sugarcrm-Login to sugarcrm application with google account

Tags: sugarcrm

I'm able to setup sugarcrm to my local machine. Also I've a bit of knowledge of studio. Now I've got a requirement like login to sugarcrm using google account. If user want to login to sugar he/she'll have to use his/her  google credential. If the credential is correct and the email id matches with the email id for a user in user module, the he'll be able to login to sugar.

I'm pretty new to sugar so please provide help. Please write if the problem description is not clear to you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your goal is to enable Google Authentication within SugarCRM, which would mean a rewrite of the entire login page and process. I think that's beyond the scope of a SO post, but I think you'd start here: https://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator/

SugarCRM does come equipped with the Zend Library, including a lot of classes for working with Google APIs, so that's a plus.

A simpler answer, if it meets requirements, is to set the Users' user_names to their google email addresses, either @gmail.com or @googleappdomain.com, whatever. The draw back here is that the accounts aren't actually linked with Google, so passwords won't stay in sync.